# Issue i am facing with dateFormat.parse(string)?

Tags: java, date

I have below code snippet

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
      "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
 String processedContentDate="2012-04-10 12:53:28.033";   
 java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(processedContentDate);
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(
 parsedDate.getTime());
```

I get parsed date as Tue Apr 10 00:53:28 IST 2012 and timestamp as 2012-04-10 00:53:28.033 .  **i want to get the time exactly as 12:53:28.033(as in my original string)
 not 00:53:28.033.**  Not getting why 12:53:28 is getting converted to 00:53:28. what should I do to get 12:53:28?

**EDIT:** After getting the response, I tried this small programme where current time is 14:34:38.899
but at both lines i.e at line 1 and line 2, I got below parsed date 
2012-04-10 14:34:38.899
As per reply I should have got 02:34:38.899 at line 1 as date format is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS")`

```
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    String strDate=date.toString();
    java.util.Date parsedDate;
    java.util.Date parsedDate2;
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
     "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");// line 1
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
     "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");//line 2
     try {
         java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
          strDate=timestamp.toString();


            parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);//line1
            parsedDate2 = dateFormat2.parse(strDate);//line2
```

Comment: How is your dateFormat variable defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your `dateFormat` like that

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

`HH` instead of `hh`. See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @MSach: The time `12:00:00` can be interpreted as midday or midnight. But `14:00:00` is not ambiguous. That is why it works on both. Any hour over 12 is not ambuguous.

Comment: amazing fact.it mean hh:mm:ss format,anything between 12 to 1 will be treated as AM thats why it converting 12.30 to 0.30. Right? Another interesting fact with format hh:mm:ss, how will i determine that it is am or pm. like 7.30 can be am or pm.

Answer (score 1):

Your date format must be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

`hh` is hours in am/pm, while `HH` is hours in a day (that's where you mistake is). See [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: with HH:mm:ss.SSS, if i have time string  as "00:53:28.033" then i will get the parsed date as "00:53:28.033" but if time string  is "12:53:28.033" i will get it as "12:53:28.033". So it will be same format of whatever i am passing in string. RIGHT?

Comment: No, if you use `hh`, the first example will be in `am` while the second example will be in `pm`.

Comment: Thanks Elite gentlemen. One more question with java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()); we get timestamp in HH:mm:ss.SSS. format. is that correct? This is what iam seeing in my dubugger atleast.

Answer (score 1):

As per definition of [Date.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) and [Timestamp.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString%28%29), the `.toString()` output is always using a 24-hour clock. If you want to show the time using AM/PM, you should use the dateformatter to print the date.  As you are using the same date/time as a source for both (`strDate` will use 14:34), when you parse the date, the `SimpleDateFormat` using the 12-hour clock is "lenient" and allows parsing of 14 as an hour.

If you set

```
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

you'll probably find that the `dateFormat.parse(strDate)` will fail.

To print dates, I would never rely on `toString`, but always use a formatter.

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(parsedDate)); // should show ...02:36...
System.out.println(dateFormat2.format(parsedDate)); // should show ...14:36...
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(parsedDate2)); // should show ...02:36...
System.out.println(dateFormat2.format(parsedDate2)); // should show ...14:36...
```

Comment: it mean hh:mm:ss format,anything between 12 to 1 will be treated as AM thats why it converting 12.30 to 0.30. Right? Another interesting fact with format hh:mm:ss, how will i determine that it is am or pm. like 7.30 can be am or pm

Comment: You'd need the AM/PM marker in your formatting string, so the format would be `hh:mm:ss a` which would allow you to parse `02:36:00 am` and `02:36:00 pm`.

Comment: beny23 suppose current time is 12.30 and I have this code java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
String strDate=date.toString();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
         "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS "
 parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate); it gives me times as 0.30. what i want is it also tells me whether it is am or pm? i dont see this information anywhere in parsedDate variable in debugger

Comment: AM/PM is just a representation, so you wouldn't see this in the debugger. 24-hour clock: 0:30 == 12:30 AM.  The problem is that you are using a 24-hour clock representation (`date.toString`) and parsing it as a 12-hour clock (`dateFormat.parseDate`).  If you want to just show the current time in the 12-hour clock, use `String dateStr = new SimpleDateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS a").format(new Date())`

Comment: Thanks for beautiful clarification

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fmt.parse("yourdate");
SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");String myDate = fmtOut.format(date);

If yourdate is 2016-06-10 12:06:43, then output will be 10-06-2016 12:06 pm.